# ¿Por qué Python ejecuta una condición que no se da?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo python y haciendo una sencilla aplicación que, dada una cantidad, la somete a una serie de condiciones para ejecutar una operación u otra. Es algo así:

```
val = input("Cantidad: ")

if val < 300:
    print "Primer escalon"
    valor = val * 0.25
    print "Honorarios:"
    print valor
    exit

if val > 300 < 600:
    print "Segundo escalon"
    valor = 75
    resto = val - 300
    segun = resto * 0.22
    valor = valor + segun
    print "Honorarios:"
    print valor
    exit

if val > 600 < 3000:
    print "Tercer escalon"
    valor = 141
    resto = val - 600
    segun = resto * 0.15
    valor = valor + segun
    print "Honorarios:"
    print valor
    exit
```

Cuando introduzco un valor inferior a 300 funciona, pero si introduzco otro valor para ir al tercer escalón, lo identifica como segundo y tercero a la vez:

```
jc@debian:~/$ python minuta.py
Cuantia: 1000
Tercer escalon
Honorarios:
201.0
Segundo escalon
Honorarios:
229.0
```

¿Qué me falta? ¿Por qué identifica el entero 1000 como que cumple la segunda y tercera condición si sólo debería aparecer la tercera? Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes mal expresadas las condiciones. Has usado una comparación encadenada, que es algo de la forma:

```
expresion1 [comparacion1] expresion2 [comparacion2] expresion3
```

y que para Python es equivalente a:

```
(expresion1 [comparacion1] expresion2) and (expresion2 [comparacion2] expresion3)
```

Así que tu segundo `if` en el que has puesto:

```
val > 300 < 600
```

equivale a

```
(val > 300) and (300 < 600)
```

Ya puedes ver que para el caso `val=1000` se cumple, ya que 1000 es mayor de 300, y por otro lado 300 es menor que 600 (esta segunda parte no afecta al resultado, al ser verdad siempre).

Lo que tú querías poner es:

```
300 < val < 600
```

Es decir, que `val` esté comprendido entre 300 y 600. Y así con el resto de condiciones.

Comment: Jo, cómo no me di cuenta!! Mil gracias.